# Gerrit rest api does not work when branch name has /

Tags: rest, api, powershell, gerrit

I am calling gerrit rest api in powershell. 
My branchname is branchname/test (contains a slash)

When i do a GET operation for below url  it works. Here branchname is  "develop" and does not contain a slash /.
https://myserver.com/changes/Manifest~**develop**~I533a17c9d3e6e1147a7ab9186fb02589922dbeef/revisions/a5ac8c910b39fd5d6a4e42226eeb37abeeda12ce/files

however when i use a branch name with a slash e.g.  branchname/test,  my query fails! 
https://myserver.com/changes/Manifest~**branchname/test**~I533a17c9d3e6e1147a7ab9186fb02589922dbeef/revisions/a5ac8c910b39fd5d6a4e42226eeb37abeeda12ce/files

I am passing this url in below command

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $fileQuery -Method Get -Credential $user -UseBasicParsing).Content
```

Comment: Fails ........how?

Answer (score 1):

You need to URL encode it. In your case the branchname should be: `branchname%2Ftest`

See: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api.html#encoding